# Need help using json

Tags: c, arrays, json, string

I am having difficulty handling strings and arrays in jansson.

```
unsigned char number[10]; // contains a hex array using upto 6 bytes
```

Now I did

```
json_object_set_new(foo,"bar",json_string(number));
```

This results in an empty json object.

I have also tried this

```
number[6]='\0';
```

followed by

```
json_object_set_new(foo,"bar",json_string(number));
```

yet the result is same.
I can not undestand why.

Comment: Check the return value of any function you call.

Comment: json_string is failing so returning NULL

Comment: So, looking at the documentation, the argument of `json_string` is required to be a valid UTF-8 string. It probably isn't in your program.

Answer (score 0):

sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jansson.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned char number[10] = "123456";
    char *result;
    json_t *root = json_object();
    json_t *foo = json_object();
    json_object_set(root, "foo", foo);
    json_object_set_new(foo,"bar",json_string(number));

    result = json_dumps(root, 0);
    printf("%s\n", result);//{"foo": {"bar": "123456"}}
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```